# Can someone explain how I made this code work?

Tags: python

So we had a lab activity a few days ago where we had to print the number of letters in a word alphabetically. No duplicate printing of the same letter. For some reason, I got it to work by typing the condition if x[i] == x[i-1] but after coming home, I can't wrap my head on how I came up with this and how this works in the first place. Can someone explain to me how it worked? Even though it worked I want to know the logic behind that "if" condition. Thanks and good day.

```
word = (sorted(str.upper(raw_input("Enter your word(s): "))))

def counts(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        count = 0
        for g in range(len(x)):
            if x[g] == x[i]:    count += 1
            else:   continue
        if x[i] == x[i-1]:
            continue
        else:
            print x[i],"occurs", count,"times."

counts(word)
```

Comment: Yeah, at first glance I don't know how it works either. though I'm quite certain I could figure it out by tracing it through a debugger, an exercise you could do yourself.  But you'd be better off focusing your efforts on writing code that is more understandable.

Comment: This works because your list, words, is a sorted list of individual characters. Therefore, the condition you mention, x[i]==x[i-1], is a way to only use the FIRST occurrence of an individual character. I'd encourage you to use some print statements in the outer and inner loops, to watch how this code actually works.

Comment: Ah, right.  Missed the `sorted` part.

Comment: You should use enumerate instead of range len. `for index, value in enumerate(iterable_variable):  ...`

Comment: If you write code that works not by design but by luck, then good luck trying to understand it

Comment: If current_letter is the same as previous_letter don't print anything.  The net result is you only print counts the first time you encounter a letter.  There is one special case when `i` is `0`.  Then you are comparing `x[0]` to `x[-1]`.  `0` indexes the first item in the sequence and `-1` indexes the last item in the sequence.  Since your data is sorted this will work without issue, but it would be a problem if your input was just repetitions of a single letter or if your input was simply one letter.  Then your loop would print nothing.

Comment: @Guillaume: How is that sort of scolding helpful?  The OP is making a good faith effort to learn.  Even experienced developers will sometimes look at old code and think "Wait.  What was my logic here?" This is just a beginner having a more compressed version of that experience.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks for understanding. I just started learning Python a few weeks ago and I had no prior developing experience so I'm glad to meet people like you that try to help newbies like me as much as they could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first line,

```
word = (sorted(str.upper(raw_input("Enter your word(s): "))))
```

your input is sorted in alphabetically and changed to upper case.
Ex) banana -> AAABNN
Like the above example, the same characters are continuously gathered.
Next,

```
for i in range(len(x)):
```

This code iterates our input.
At first iteration, x[0] is A.
And then,

```
for g in range(len(x)):
        if x[g] == x[i]:    count += 1
        else:   continue
```

This code counts how many same characters are continuous.
At first iteration, x[0] = A and there are three As in AAABNN.
So count is 2.
But without

```
if x[i] == x[i-1]:
        continue
```

It prints `A occurs 3 times.` because of x[1] and x[2].
So you can skip iterations of x[1] and x[2] by using the above code.
Your code can be optimized like this,

```
def counts(x):
    count = 0
    prev_character = x[0]
    while len(x) > 0:
        curr_character = x[0]
        if prev_character == curr_character:
            count += 1
            x.pop(0)
        else:
            print prev_character, "occurs", count, "times."
            prev_character = curr_character
            count = 0
    if count > 0:
        print prev_character," occurs", count, "times."
```

Comment: Technically "banana -> AAABNN" should be "banana -> `['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'N', 'N']`"

Comment: That cleared my mind. Thanks for this detailed explanation!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Oh, you are right! I missed it. Thank you :)
I'm glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

The `if` stattement

```
 if x[i] == x[i-1]
```

prevents printing out anything, when current character is the same as previous character.
I think the program is for `counting` the number of `characters` in the entered `word`. It starts by collection the word variable and sorting it alphebetically. Then, by looping through the length of word, it does compare the number of instances of each characters. you might need to call the defined function counts like this:

```
word = (sorted(str.upper(raw_input("Enter your word(s): "))))

def counts(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        count = 0
        for g in range(len(x)):
            if x[g] == x[i]:    count += 1
            else:   continue
        if x[i] == x[i-1]:
            continue
        else:
            print x[i],"occurs", count,"times."

print counts(word)
```

See it in action, I typed in 'Hello world':
[image]

Comment: I have already changed the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -2):

For me, it also doesn't make any sense at `if x[i] == x[i-1]:`. It just an `if` statement to judge if the left word is same as its.

But I could help you make it simpler.

```
def counts(x):
    for alpha in sorted(set(x)):
        print alpha,"occurs", x.count(alpha),"times."
```